# Porting tastypie APIs to Django Rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, tastypie

I have a large user base for my app, and i use "tastypie" to develop APIs for the backend. I am trying to move to django rest framework.

I have been using **ApiKeyAuthentication** of tastypie which generates an apikey when a new **auth_user** is created. How do i port this whole authentication mechanism to django rest framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django REST framework provides a basic token authentication.
You need to create the token for the user - easily doable via signals - and configure DRF to use the token auth.

The documentation should provides everything you need at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

If not, let us know how we can improve it :)

Comment: Thanks Linovia. Is this possible with django 1.4?

Comment: The latest DRF version that supports Django 1.4 is 3.1.3 and has the token authentication, so you can support it though I'd suggest upgrading Django.